# SSH vagrant Git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant

I am using MacOs, Virtualbox, and vagrant. I was trying to run `git fetch` after ssh-ing to my VM using `vagrant ssh`. I keep getting the error

> Permission denied (publickey).

I have generated ssh key on my local machine. and added the public key to my bitbucket accordingly. So, i suspected there is something wrong with my ssh key, I have looked at so many online solutions and tried many of them but still couldn't resolve the problem.

However, I noticed that I don't have a `~/.ssh/config` file inside the vm. could that be the reason? I am very new to SSH so I might be missing a simple silly solution here.

however, in my i have the `~/.ssh/config` in my local and it contains the following:

```
Host 127.0.0.1
AddKeysToAgent yes
ForwardAgent yes
```

in my vagrantFile I have set the `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`

And when I run vagrant provision i get the following error:

> ```
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. 
> The output for this command should be in the log above. 
> Please read the output to determine what went wrong.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A config file is not mandatory. If your SSH URL is `git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>`, it should work.

Try with a config including `Host *` in case 127.0.0.1 is not the right approach.
See "[Using SSH agent forwarding with Vagrant][1]"

> You need to replace `your.domain.com` with either the domain or the IP address of your Vagrant box.
> You can wildcard this with `Host *`, but this is a really bad idea because it lets every server you SSH to access your keys.

So '`*`' is just for testing.
[1]: https://wildlyinaccurate.com/using-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant/